# How to prev and next button click navigate the nested array into the react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

One of my requirement into the react is to put the button inside the array.map on each nested links and also contains the button prev and next.

Here is the Format of the my array collections::

```js
const myTest = [
      {
        links: [
          {
            id: "1",
            name: "One",
            links: [
              {
                id: "1.1",
                name: "11"
              },
              {
                id: "1.2",
                name: "12"
              },
              {
                id: "1.3",
                name: "13"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            name: "Two",
            links: [
              {
                id: "2.1",
                name: "21"
              },
              {
                id: "2.2",
                name: "22"
              },
              {
                id: "2.3",
                name: "23"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Here I tried using the react code and code as following ::

```js
let menuItems = myTest[0].links;
    const { itemCount } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="listContainer">
          {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
            <div>
              <Row className="rowContainer">
                <a
                  style={{ paddingRight: "10px" }}
                  href="#"
                  onClick={this.handlePrevious}
                >
                  &laquo;
                </a>

                {item.links.map(
                  (subItem, subIndex) =>
                    subIndex < itemCount && (
                      <div style={{ paddingRight: "20px" }}>{subItem.name}</div>
                    )
                )}
                <a href="#" onClick={this.handleNext}>
                  &raquo;
                </a>
              </Row>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Once user click on next it will move to next available items in array and same as previous.
I have tried and initially I am able to display the itemCount only 2 from the array but once I am click on next and previous how can we navigate inside map that I am confused .

Could someone take a look into the following URL all the code which I have been tried in this codesandbox URL

[Codesandbox URL which I tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-7qp1b?file=/index.js)

Let me know if any other further information required?

Comment: You want to get the next page when click to button "Next Page", is that what you want?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example in your question, and be more specific about what you want your code to do, and what isn't working. We shouldn't need to guess what you want your code to do.

Comment: @Van Tho - Yes I want next page when click on next button means it should display name 13 and when user click on next button other array then it will display 23